# Change button style with angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, button

I have 3 buttons and I want change its style when the button was clicked. I don't know if angular has its own function like ng-class, ng-click or similar, but I not get it to works.

```
<button class="btn1" ng-click="function1"></button>
<button class="btn2" ng-click="function2"></button>
<button class="btn3" ng-click="function3"></button>
```

is possible call to another css class from js(in the function)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for starters

```
<button 
    class="btn_theme btn1" 
    ng-class="{'clicked':clicker}" 
    type="submit" ng-click="select1()">Hello</button>
```

with this in the controller

```
  $scope.select1 = function() {
    $scope.clicker = !$scope.clicker
  }
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/zKsYoD3coPlZRHQkRQO1?p=preview

Comment: If you set up a plnkr, I can help connect everything up

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class dynamically on ng-click.

```
<li ng-class="{'xyzclass':addClass}" ng-click="addClass = TRUE"><a href="#users" >Users</a></li>
```

Comment: how? I need use a function, is possible function+add css in the same call?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function definition you could set some variable on the scope, which you could then use inside an `ng-class` directive.

**Example**

Somewhere in your controller:

```
$scope.function1 = function () {
  $scope.clickedButton1 = true;
}
```

In your template:

```
<button 
  class="btn1" 
  ng-class="{'button1Clicked': clickedButton1}" 
  ng-click="function1()">Button1</button>
```